# Push Rejected Heroku Node.JS

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

So, I tried to install canvas into node.js in order to make a welcome image system. After using GitHub Desktop and pushing it to origin, Heroku just sent this error:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.20.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.10
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > canvas@2.6.1 install /tmp/build_b4f1ac50_/node_modules/canvas
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.J72ia/_logs/2021-01-12T16_13_34_801Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "discordbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.4.1",
    "giphy-js-sdk-core": "^1.0.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.10",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1",
    "youtube-notification": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

I then visited the websites advised, checked everything and none of it worked. I ended up just uninstalling canvas, but I would like to know how to make it work. I also visited a few other websites but everything I tried did nothing. I am currently on node version v14.15.0 and npm version v6.14.8. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1563) GitHub issue? It may help.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes I have but it did not fix my issue.